# Scala: Converting 2D list into 1D

Tags: java, scala, list

I have a scala list

val x = List[(a,b), (c,d), (d,e)]

I want to convert above 2D list into 1D.

expected output val x = List(a,b,c,d,d,e)

I have tried using "x.flatten", but it didn't work.

How can I convert 2D list into 1D.

Comment: expected output val x = List[a,b,c,d,d,e], sorry for typo error.

Comment: In that code `(a, b)` is not a list its `Tuple2[A, B]` - a single variable so you can't flatten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
List((a, b), (c, d), (d, e)).map { case (x, y) => List(x, y) }.flatten
```

or

```
List((a, b), (c, d), (d, e)).flatMap { case (x, y) => List(x, y) }
```

Comment: This also works and is a bit more generic: `.flatMap(_.productIterator)`